# Invalid AMI option for Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to setup a Rails server on AWS using Elastic Beanstalk. I am following the guide [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html). I managed to configure the EB CLI, and I am at the part where I am trying to deploy the app to an EB environment. However, I am getting an error that the AMI option I provided is inval

```
[rails-beanstalk$] eb create first-beanstalk-env -sr aws-beanstalk-service-role
 WARNING: You have uncommitted changes.
 Creating application version archive "app-8bc6-160112_090122".
 Uploading rails-beanstalk/app-8bc6-160112_090122.zip to S3. This may take  a while.
 Upload Complete.
 ERROR: Configuration validation exception: Invalid option value: 'ami- 48eb8128' (Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration', OptionName: 'ImageId'): No EC2 ImageId found with id: 'ami-48eb8128'
```

I don't remember ever setting an AMI (or what that even is), so I am very confused as to why I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what's up with that error, but I find the EB CLI quite fragile. Try to take a different approach and create the environment via the aws web console and not via the cli. 
Once this is ready, use `eb init` to setup beanstalk for your local project and then `eb deploy <env-name>` to push your project to the newly created env.

If the error persists, try to change the deployment zone. AWS sometimes have local bugs in some regions.

**EDIT**: this seems to be an issue with AWS. I tried it myself and it fails with the default setup in all aws zones.

**EDIT 2**: this is now confirmed with amazon:

> Unfortunately we are experiencing an issue on our side related to
>   Beanstalk and the default Ruby AMI in different regions. We are
>   already investigating the issue and we plan to fix this as soon as
>   possible. I will update you through this support case once we will get
>   any update from the Elastic Beasntalk service team.

Comment: Thank you for that response. I just tried that, and after going through the web console, I managed to get to the last step in setting up the environment, but when I clicked on launch, I got the same exact error (different AMI id though...). I am really confused now

Comment: sounds like an aws issue. nothing to do with you.

Comment: @PeterBenavides see the edit above. aws are experiencing issues

Answer (score 0):

`'ami- 48eb8128'`
This has a space in it and is not a valid AMI ID